# problem installing oracle instant client on my centOS machine

Tags: centos

I have downloaded and extracted the rpm package **instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.1.0.zip** from oracle website and extracted it in **/usr/lib/** where the current path is: **/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/** as explained in **http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php**. But the following command

```
./configure --with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/
```

gives the following error:

```
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

The platform is CentOS 6.5

If `./configure` is supposed to be the name of file in the extracted package, I cant find it there!

Please help me in this! I have been googling for this whole day with no chance!

Comment: Is there a configure file in current directory and it has execute permissions?

Comment: @alpertek, No, I dont think so. I could not fine such a file in the whole `/usr/lib` !!!

Comment: To install oracle instant client refer to end of that page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html. The link you give have instructions to recompile php with oci8 support.